# Find the number of children, given that the estate was divided evenly between them

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Problem of the Week](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/resources/potw/2014-15/POTWE-14-AE-FC-15-P.pdf) at University of Waterloo:

> A man died leaving some money in his estate. All of this money was to be
>   divided among his children in the following manner:

- $x$ to the first born plus $1/16$ of what remains, then
- $2x$ to the second born plus $1/16$ of what then remains, then
- $3x$ to the third born plus $1/16$ of what then remains, and so on.

When the distribution of the money was complete, each child received the same amount and no money was left over. Determine the number of children.

Can anyone hint at a strategy I could use to solve this? I've tried everything I could think of. All I want is a hint, though. No solutions please.

Comment: Hint1: algebra; Hint2: series.

Comment: Try to solve it from the end (don't know the right translation from the russian, I mean that you should watch at the end of the process, then the previous step and so on)

Comment: Write down the equation for the first two distributions to be equal given that the initial sum is $A$ to determine $A$ in terms of $x$. Then check it works all the way down.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that he left behind *some* money; then we can choose units in such a way that he left behind $1$ unit of money. Then the first payment is $x+(1-x)/16=15x/16+1/16$. This is equal to the second payment, which is $2x+(1-2x-15x/16-1/16)/16=2x+15/256-47x/256=465x/256+15/256$.

Clearing denominators, $240x+16=465x+15$. Now solving we get $225x=1$ or $x=1/225$. So everyone received the amount $15(1/225)/16+1/16=240/3600$.

So if $n$ children received $240/3600$ each, then $240n/3600=1$. What do you conclude?

Comment: mmm, the no solutions part is quite ignored, but good answer.

Comment: @Marc Unless I made an error, there is a solution. (Previously I *did* make an error that winds up with there being no solution.) I make the first remark where we assume that he left behind some money to leave open the possibility that there is no nonzero solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $y$ be the amount he left over. How much did the first born receive? How much did the second born receive?

Mathe them equal.